# How to maintain interfaces in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, typescript-typings

I am working with react and typescript

i have many folder containing a number of tsx files

each file has some interfaces to define the type of argument

```
interface IUser {
    userID: string,
    text: string,
    EmailId: string
}

interface ICreateSessionStates {
    selectedUsers: Array<IUser>,
    sessionDetails: ISessionDetails,
    entityDetails: IEntityDetails,
    domains: Array<IDomain>,
    users: Array<{
        Name: string
    }>
}

usersUpdated(users : Array<IUser>) {
    this.setState({
        selectedUsers: users
    } as ICreateSessionStates)
}
```

should all these interface be kept in on file say interface.d.ts or seperated file for each folder, what is generally done

Comment: There's no right/wrong here. Choose whatever is comfortable for you. In my opinion properties/state interfaces should be placed along with their components.

Comment: @NitzanTomer  so in your opinion, each file should have its interfaces declared in it or one file for one whole folder?

Comment: Second @NitzanTomer. Interfaces should be close to where "the come from".

Comment: It depends.  If you place all components into one file (because you don't have many of them) then fine, but once the file gets too big I break it into different files, but the interfaces always go along with the classes they serve

Comment: @NitzanTomer offers a nice approach. You could also try playing around with it. What works for me usually is having the interfaces for react components in the same file with the component itself, but if I define an interface that represents something other than a component (for example, user data retrieved from the server) I would create a separate file just to define that type, perhaps even a separate folder.